# Is it valid to use "id" attribute in sitemap?

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap

i'm making a google sitemap for my website, there will be some changes in the sitemap (delete,edit) is it valid to use the id attribute in the url tag?

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url id="1187335">
<loc>
http://www.example.com/test.html
</loc>
<lastmod>2016-06-22T18:41:34+03:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
<priority>1</priority>
</url>
```